# How to enable sudo on Xampp's php

Tags: sudo, php, xampp

Heres the problem, I'm using `laravel` and I wanted to deploy it on port `80` locally, but it says I got `no permission to listen on port 80`,

I tried `sudo php artisan serve --port=80` and it says `php` command not found, but the `php` from `xampp` works fine without `sudo`.

Additionally, I tried an external PHP extension via `apt-get` on which `sudo php` works, but I want to stick with Xampp's PHP for consistency because un using its MySQL and Apache.

P.S my apache runs on port `8000` so port `80` is available.

Comment: There is no `Xampp's` php. On your system you have php installed or not but it doesn't only `belong` to Xampp but makes part of it. And usually application run by another user than root are not allowed to use ports < 8000 for safety reasons. Anyway you could for example run it on port 8080 and in your firewall forward port 80 to that port 8080.

Comment: i think you misunderstand the problem